# Custom navigation control

Tags: ios, ipad

I'd like to use a couple of techniques the Reeder iPad app uses:

http://reederapp.com/ipad/

Specifically I'd like to have navigation on the left side and use a similar layout.

How do they do that? Is it just a standard navigation controller positioned on the left? Is the layout of items/thumbnails just a customized table view? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard navigation controller. You would have to create your own `UIView` that attaches itself to the side and has the `AutoresizingMask` property set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`. Setup the view with the buttons that you would like by using the `-drawRect:` and `-layoutSubviews:` methods. Depending on how much abstraction you want to do with your custom view you could have all the buttons send messages to the `UIView` then that view would pass those messages to a delegate.

Example:

```
@protocol SideNavigationBarDelegate
- (void)didTapButtonAtIndex:(NSUInteger)buttonIndex;
@end

@interface SideNavigationBar : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<SideNavigationBarDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<SideNavigationBarDelegate>)aDelegate;

- (void)addButtonWithIcon:(UIImage *)icon;

- (void)removeButtonAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end

@implementation SideNavigationBar
...
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<SideNavigationBarDelegate>)aDelegate {
...
    [self setDelegate:aDelegate];
    [self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height])];
...
}

- (void)addButtonWithIcon:(UIImage *)icon {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, 44.0f)];
UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, 44.0f)];
[iconView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[iconView setImage:icon];
[button addSubview:iconView];
...set the target and action for the button...
[[self buttons] addObject:button];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { ...draw buttons on view... }

@end
```

As for the thumbnails that is a customized table view (or grid view in this case). Instead of making your own, take a look at this: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView